# Замена слов в строке Java

Tags: java, строки, replace

Есть строка, допустим

`String a = "HelloWorld";`

Мне надо заменить слово "Hello" на "GoodBye". Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: О `String#replace`  не слышали? Вообще-то, во многих языках есть похожий метод.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

выглядит он так

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

т.е. он меняет символ или последовательность символов `target` на `replacement` и возвращает данную новую строку.

```
String Str = "HelloWorld";
System.out.println(Str.replace("Hello", "GoodBye")); // выведет GoodByeWorld
```

Comment: А можно использовать Str.replace(слово 1, слово 2) БЕЗ System.out.print ???

Comment: @PetrSedov Конечно. В примере в ответе `System.out.println()` служит только для вывода на экран результата, который возвращает метод `replace()`. Т.е. результат  вызова `replace()` служит входным параметром для метода `System.out.println()`. Этот результат можно сохранить в переменой или использовать любым другим способом, как и любое другое значение класса `String`.